What's the TV documentary where two elderly sisters enter a care home?
I saw a TV documentary seven or eight years ago. It could have been British TV. It was a documentary that followed two elderly sisters (may be twins) who entered a care home. 
One sister had an outgoing personality and was the dominant sister, socially, while the other sister was quiet. 
As the film followed the couple as they adapt to care home, the older sister who had been the stronger personality withers and the quiet sister becomes the bedrock of the two. The elder sister goes downhill emotionally trying to adapt to the care home.  
The elder sister's son then visits with his wife and two children. The older sister is excited to see her son and the two grand children. However, when the son arrives, the mother puts on a brave face saying she is happy in the home (which she is not) and the son goes outside to play football with his two young children while the elderly woman looks out of the window saddened that she has little communication with them during their visit. 
At the end of the documentary the son is back at his home, sitting comfortably on his sofa with his children and the interviewer asks from off camera "What will happen to you when you get old, will you go into a home?". To which the son replies that he would never want to be placed in a home and would expect his kids to look after him.  A very sad ending.  
Can't find details of this programme and it had such an impact on me. 
